# Authorize all actions under specific controller (example: adminController)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorize

i want to authorize all action under adminController. how can i do that. i have a database with Roles and User. 
1. Administrator
2. Member

i want only Administrators can access to all action in adminController.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class controller() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I follow what you are asking, I've done this to restrict access to the SiteAdminController:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Site Admin")]
public class SiteAdminController : BaseController
```

That restricts access to the actions of  my `SiteAdminController` to users in that role.

Comment: thanks but i want to use my custom role (include Users, Role Table in my database).. and how can i do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  So, for instance, if you use the aspnetdb user/roles you can set up whatever roles you want and associate users to them there.  Are you saying that you have your own user/role table in your app's DB that you want to use in the `[Authorize(Roles=  <something from your DB>)]` line?